# Rename virtual machine in vSphere using rest api

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I could not find anything in the official documentation :-(
Is it possible to rename a virtual machine in vsphere using the api?

I want to use the api. No SDK.

Here is the doc link: https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/v7.0U2-deprecated/vcenter/vm/guest.identity/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, that is not available within the vSphere Automation (REST) API today.

Comment: I'm also looking to rename a template in vsphere 7.0? Is it possible with rest API?

Answer (score 0):

The listed APIs are the ones publicly provided by the API explorer in vCenter Server. They don't recommend renaming the instance name and this is not a supported operation.

Comment: That's really unfortunate :-(

Answer (score 0):

'Update Data Sets' via patch will do the job, however it only starts at vSphere 8.0.

https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/v8.0.0/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/vm/data-sets/data_set/patch/.

Another clumsy workaround is to use Customization file, but it requires VM in PoweredOff state.